# Magento 2 - product image url without hash

Tags: magento2

The product image URL of a Magento 2 store is like:

> example.com/media/media/catalog/product/cache/8b8f1e61e783c045142bcb34d1e0b2a9/m/y/my-product-image.jpg

I would like to remove the “cache/8b8f1e61e783e783c045142bcb34d1e0b2a9/” from the URL, because I have a lot of 404 error in logs due to that.

As you know, each time the cache is cleaned and regenerated, the URL hash change and the search engines does not find the previews one.

Has anyone ever had this kind of situation before? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```